# Backup SQL Server with ASP VB via IP

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ip

Can I backup SQL Server database to a client drive?

```
Dim contamp As New SqlConnection(PyrDLL.Con(Session("IP")).ConnectionString)

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = contamp
cmd.CommandText = "backup database MovePyr to disk='D:MovePyr.bak'"

contamp.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
contamp.Close()
```

That's my code but its not creating a `MovePyr.bak` on the client's drive, it creates it on the server drive

Can I write it to the client drive? (session("IP")) is client IP

Thanks...

Comment: No you cannot - after all: would you **really** want a remote server like SQL Server have full access to your own local harddisk ?? I would definitely not!! What you can do is write it to a **UNC path** (`\\server\share\directory`) that the server has access to - this can be on some other computer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

backup database MovePyr to disk='\\computer_name_here\d$\MovePyr.bak'

Do you have write access rights to this drive? Check with WINKEY + R then type:

\\computer_name_here\d$

or

\\ip_of_computer_here\d$

If you need to supply credentials (username\password) then your database isn't being created because of Error 5 (access denied). If you can access via IP rather than Computer Name then it's a DNS error not resolving but it's probably no write permission

Why not compile your code, place on the target machine and use a Scheduled Task (either logged on or not (so it always runs)), it will ask you for credentials to run it with and create no window then you can check daily for the backup.